# Python Twisted dynamic protocols for sending packets at runtime

Tags: python, twisted, distributed-system

I've recently started using Python Twisted, and while its very complex I'm really liking it! I've tried searching for the answer to this but I keep coming up dry so I was hoping someone here is a twisted guru:

I have a large/complex distributed system setup in a hierarchical format with masters, slaves, subslaves, etc..
At several points in my code depending on the packet received, I have a need to send a packet of data to another node. The node the data needs to be sent to is not known before calling `reactor.run()` so I feel like the answer might be different. I would like the connection to be TCP for reliability, but it only needs to send one packet. Sometimes I need an ACK back and sometimes I don't, but after that the connection can always die. The current way I've been handling this is by keeping a reference to the `reactor` in my class that is required to send the packet and calling:

```
tmpConn = MyClientFactory(dataToSend)
self.reactor.connectTCP(ADDR, PORT, tmpConn)
```

I feel that this might present a few issues however:

- What happens to garbage collection if I don't keep the reference to the `tmpConn`.
- If I do keep a reference to it in my class it ends up being garbage anyway because it only needed to send one packet.

As I said there are many different Factories all doing things like this at the same time so I wonder if this is the best way to handle this situation. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Here is a code snippet so the question is more clear.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory, ClientFactory

class OneShotProtocol(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, addr, data):
        self.myaddr = addr
        self.mydata = data

    def connectionMade(self):
        # We know we have a connection here so send the data
        self.transport.write(self.mydata)
        # Now we can kill the connection
        self.transport.loseConnection()

class OneShotFactory(ClientFactory):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.mydata = data

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return OneShotProtocol(addr, self.mydata)

class ListenProtocol(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, addr, factory):
        self.myaddr = addr
        #NOTE: I only save this because I've read multiple reactors are possible
        self.factory = factory

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        if(data == 'stuff'):
            #Alert the other node!
            tmpConn = OneShotFactory('The British are coming')
            self.factory.reactor.connectTCP(ADDR, PORT, tmpConn)
        # Moving on...

class ListenFactory(Factory):
    def __init__(self, reactor):
        self.reactor = reactor

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return OneShotProtocol(addr, self)

l = ListenFactory(reactor)
reactor.listenTCP(PORT, l)
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a great way to implement the behavior you want.

You don't have to worry very much about garbage collection of your factory.  The reactor will keep a reference to it (you passed it to `connectTCP`, after all) for as long as it needs to and then forget about it.  If you also forget about it then Python's garbage collector will clean it up for you before too long.

The only adjustment you might want to make is to use the cool new ["endpoint" APIs](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/issues/38#issuecomment-35992580) instead of using `connectTCP` directory.  This doesn't change the basic idea of the solution, it just gives you a little bit more flexibility that you might someday benefit from.